# How does one calculate distance between geo coordinates on the side of a square & one inside the square when it is tilted relative to latitudes?

Tags: trigonometry

Imagine a rectangular plot of land that happens to be parallel to the lines of latitude. I know the geographic coordinates of the upper left corner; therefore I know the longitude of any point along the left side. There is a point somewhere inside the square and I know its geographic coordinates. I therefore have all the information I need to calculate the distance between a point inside the square and a point across from it on the left side. A line drawn between these points would be perpendicular to the left side.

Now imagine that this plot of land is not parallel to the lines of latitude, it is tilted right 30 degrees to them. Now the upper left corner coordinates are different from the lower left, and every point along the left side has a different longitude. Is there some way that I could adjust for this so that I could still, just knowing the coordinates at the upper left corner and bottom left corner, derive the coordinates of a point on the left side so a line drawn between the point inside the square and the point on the left side would still be perpendicular to the left side?  By the way, I also need to do this from that same point to the bottom of the rectangle, which of course is also now tilted 30 degrees.

This is a real-life problem, I'm trying to translate the geographic coordinates of that point inside the rectangle into Cartesian coordinates that increase from 0 on the left side of a computer's UI, and from the bottom screen. The "plot of land" is actually a city bus yard and the "point inside the square" a bus whose location I am trying to accurately reflect in the computer's UI, where the bus yard is not tilted.

Note: these distances are relatively short. I am using Spherical Law of Cosines to measure distance between points. Also, I am not a mathematician, I'm a programmer.

[image: image of tilted Rectangle]

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would do it, since you seem to know how to obtain distances with the Spherical Law of Cosines:

0. We define $A$ and $B$ as the corner points on your left side, and $C$ as the interior point.
1. Use the Spherical Law of Cosines to render all three sides of $\triangle ABC$ and the angle at $A$. You should get the following for $AB$:

$\cos(AB)=\sin(Lat(A))\sin(Lat(B))+\cos(Lat(A))\cos(Lat(B))\cos(Lon(A)-Lon(B))$

where latitude and longitude are Lat and Lon respectively. Similar formulas apply for $BC$ and $AC$. Angle $A$ is similarly rendered:

$\cos(\angle A)=\cos(AB)\cos(AC)+\sin(AB)\sin(AC)\cos(BC)$

where the side lengths come from the previous formula.

2. Draw your altitude $\overline{CD}$ and apply the Spherical Law of Sines (which I assume you also know) to right $\triangle ACD$. Thereby

$\sin(CD)=\sin(AC)\sin(\angle A).$

3. Since you say the distances are relatively short, render $CD$ the smaller root (less than 90°) corresponding to the sine calculated above.

Comment: Thanks, Oscar.  Your response is clearly stated and easy to follow.  But I do have a few questions because actually, I am not familiar with the Law of Sines.  I researched the Internet but while I learned a bit, I still need to ask:  In 2 above, sin(CD) = sin(CA)sin(angleA):  Is CA is the same as AC computed prior to this?  Also:  I don't understand "render CD the acute angle root corresponding to the sine calculated above. " Finally, we ae solving for length of CD; it is opposite known angle A, and we know length of hypotenuse AC.  Can we use "Right triangle trig?"   sin(angleA) = CD/AC?

Comment: In the example you gave, unless you want precision to within a tenth of an inch,  you can just treat this as a problem in Euclidean plane geometry. No spherical geometry needed! Why? The percentage  fluctuations in angles is about $10^{(-5)}$. The higher-order quadratic corrections that are needed to improve the Euclidean model would change the answers by a similar factor. A bus lot dimension of 1000 ft divided by 100,000 is very tiny!

Comment: Notes: (1) CA is the same as AC. (2) When you have the sine of an angle or arc, the angle/arc can be either of two supplementary values. We want the smaller, acute one. (3) I actually find the spherical formulas easier to work with. Using Euclidean geometry is tricky because the latitude and longitude circles are not congruent (except at the Equator).